# How to access a implemented property in Class that implements specific interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to access an implemented property variable in a Class that implements a specific Interface, of GameObject

Each class will have a different name, I want them to implement the same interface to access the variable implemented on that interface.

How Can I find a way if Scripts to implement as below

**SampleClass.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SampleClass : MonoBehaviour, ISampleInterface
{

    public int sampleVariable 
        { get => throw new System.NotImplementedException(); 
        set => throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }

}
```

**ISampleInterface.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

interface ISampleInterface
{
    public int sampleVariable { get; set; }
}
```

**Hierarchy view**
[image]

**not working, just an explanation of What I want**

```
sampleObject.GetComponent<ISampleInterface>().sampleVariable = ~~~
```

Comment: why exactly do you think this wouldn't work? You can totally use `GetComponent<T>` with interfaces as long as it is actually attached to that `sampleObject`

Comment: @derHugo Oh.. its totally worked.. I must have made a mistake in the code that I wrote somewhere Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: @derHugo I am very glad for making me realize my mistake.
then.. Could I get the way which would be the more safe and performance-dominant way 
between GetComponent<ISampleInterface>().sampleValue and using "is" method to find a specific Interface implemented value or method

Comment: it depends ... imho using `is` this way makes no sense at all. You either already have a more specific type reference in `someObject` - in that case why go through the interface at all? Or you somewhere allow `someObject` to be an arbitrary `Component`/`MonoBehaviour` -> why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the question. Sorry for the confusion. In your case here, as @derHugo pointed out in their answer and a comment, `GetComponent<T>()` should work with T as an interface. However, <strike>if for whatever reason it does not work, which seems like the case with your situation</strike> (see @derHugo 's comment and OP's acknowledgement on main post) you can do:

```cs
// Using LINQ.

var comps = GetComponents<Component>();

// Get all interface implementing components.
var interface_comps = comps.Where(x => x is ISampleInterface).toArray();

// Get first interface implementing component.
var first_inter_comp = comps.First(x => x is ISampleInterface);
```

Again, sorry for the misreading of your question, and thanks for pointing that out.

---

---

### Stuff beyond is for the answer for "why the Inspector does not show the property", not the question asked.

What you have there is not a variable, but a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). The inspector does not auto-detect properties, only serializable public variables (or [SerializeField] tagged private ones).

So because your variable is really a property, it does not show in the inspector.

You can do something like this:

```cs
public float sampleVariable { 
    get => this._sampleVariable; 
    set => this._sampleVariable = value; 
}

[SerializeField]
private float _sampleVariable = 0;
```

to have basically the same thing.

You can shorten the code further by doing something like:

```cs
[field: SerializeField]
public float someVariable { get; set; }
```

Here you apply the same logic as with `private` variables, by telling Unity to serialize this explicitly. The only downside is that the name that Unity will show in it's errors is, as far as I know, not the variable name but the compiler generated name for it, which might make it hard to debug if you plan to use a ton of these.

[Source](https://dev.to/jayjeckel/unity-tips-properties-and-the-inspector-1goo#:%7E:text=Using%20Properties&text=The%20Inspector%20can%20only%20display,be%20displayed%20in%20the%20Inspector.:%7E:text=%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D-,Using%20Properties,-The%20first%20step) for further reading if you wish.

Comment: I appreciate about your interest‍♂️‍♂️
However, I would rather modify the property by accessing it from another Script than modify the properties(variables) in the Inspector.
 
Therefore, I find a way to access a property(variable) in Class that implemented SampleInterface in another Script

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused by me misreading your question @J4BEZ. I have edited the question to include hopefully an answer to your question. If not, please feel free to correct me again.

Comment: Very Awesome!!! I just found this!!!
I appreciate for your effort! Thanks to your Answer I got to know 'is' operator to find a Class has implemented specific interface

Comment: Thanks to your effort and I really hope you have a peaceful day

Comment: That's absolutely wrong ... `GetComponent<T>` can totally be used on interfaces .... it will search for the first component on the object that implements that interface ... `GetComponent<ISampleInterface>().sampleVariable` .. I do see no reason whatsoever why this shouldn't be working

Comment: Also note your if check can easier be written as `if(someObject is ISampleInterface obj) { obj.someVariable = ....; }`

Comment: Note that `GetComponents<Component>()` will return the first component ... which might eg. be `Transform` or whatever so there is no guarantee whatsoever that this is actually the component you are looking for .. again OP stating it didn't wok was a wrong assumption

Answer (score 1):

Hi heres is the way to implemented on that way:

```
public interface ISampleInterface
{
   int SampleVariable { get; set; }
}
        
public class SampleComponent : MonoBehaviour, ISampleInterface
{
   private int _myVariable;
    
   public int SampleVariable
   {
       get { return _myVariable; }
       set { _myVariable = value; }
   }
}
        
public class AnotherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
       ISampleInterface sampleComponent = GetComponent<SampleComponent>();
       if (sampleComponent != null)
       {
          //Access and modify the interface properties through the component
          sampleComponent.SampleVariable = 42;
       }
    }
}
```

The AnotherScript.cs need to be attach to the same object that contains SampleComponent.
If is on a child object you can use GetComponentInChildren method

In case that the AnotherScript.cs need to find the interfaces that are in anothers gameobjects, you first need to find all the objects that inheritate from MonoBehabiour.
Like in this example

```
 void FindObjectsImplementingInterface()
{
    ISampleInterface[] objectsImplementingInterface = FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>()
        .Where(obj => obj is ISampleInterface)
        .Select(obj => obj as ISampleInterface)
        .ToArray();

    // Now you have an array of objects that implement the interface
    foreach (ISampleInterface obj in objectsImplementingInterface)
    {
        // Do something with each object
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your kind and detailed response.

Since to Your response has helped me to go beyond what I was hoping for and have a better understanding.

I was also able to serach more about the Where() and Select() functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort for I get further vision for Developing, I hope you have a joyful and peaceful day today

Answer (score 1):

As commented the question has some wrong assumption in the first place!

assuming `someObject` is either a `GameObject` or arbitrary `Component` then using

```
var sample = someObject.GetComponent<ISamepleInterface>();
sample.sampleValue = xxx;
```

works just fine!

If you anyway are going to wrap it with a check if such component exists you can also go for

```
if(someObject.TryGetComponent<ISamepleInterface>(out var sample))
{
    sample.sampleValue = xxx;
}
```

---

The [usage of `is`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76259085/7111561) imho makes no sense at all since it would mean

- either you already have `someObject` as a specific implementation type of that interface anyway

  In such case what would be the purpose of going through the interface at all then?
- You somewhere allow `someObject` to be too arbitrary

  why?

If it is about referencing such a component via interface in the Inspector

=> generally you can't as Unity doesn't serialize interfaces.

In such case you should use an `abstract class` instead

Comment: Oh Thank you very much for detail answer!!

I would like to try make a switch and objects that response to the switch

the Objects would response by one switch sign, but they would deduce different results each other.
[ ex). A Object would response by changing Sprite 
B Object would response by moving its transform ]     

In this case, A and B object need same recieve function but different response.

So, I would tried implement interface to induce different actions to be implemented

Comment: Thanks to your comments and answer so I could get to find the way what I try to do the first time was an actually worked method and find a new way!! I hope you have a joyful and peaceful day!!

Comment: @J4BEZ sounds like you can still either directly use `GetComponent<IInterface>()` or go for an abstract base class (like e.g. `Renderer` or `Collider` also does)

Comment: You are right. Being a generic function, `GetComponent<T>()` would just return the first component that fits the `component is T` statement, which would also include interfaces. Definetly the better way to do it. However the poster said that method was, for whatever reason, not working for them. Hence why I didn't use that in the answer, instead going for the `is`. But someObject directly being a specific implementation was an oversight/miss on my part. I'll fix that.

Comment: @Spacejet yeah OP just assumed wrong / [made a mistake somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76259030/how-to-access-a-implemented-property-in-class-that-implements-specific-interface/76265475?noredirect=1#comment134489538_76259030) but actually `GetComponent` according to the comment would have worked just fine ^^ The problem with `GetComponent<Component>` -> it will just return the very first component matching this type ... most probably `Transform` e.g. which is not the one you are looking for ...

Comment: I just updated the answer again, and I don't know if you saw. It is using `GetComponents<Component>` which returns all components to then iterate over. And yeah, I saw that the OP replied to you saying that it worked. I think they were asking the wrong question for the wrong reason and somehow fixed their own problem ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. I did learn something new, so thanks for correcting me nonetheless.

Comment: @Spacejet ye agree I think it all comes down to the part of the code that OP did not show us ^^

Comment: @Spacejet  & derHugo I apologize for my mistake causing inconvenience and very much appreciate for sparing your effort to guide me in a greater way than I knew like LINQ notwithstanding my mistake.

Comment: the problem has solved by `GetComponent<Interface>()`

I would like to thank you once again for your sincere answer despite the problematic question and hope you have a peaceful day.

Comment: No problem, happy to help here. I am glad you managed to fix the problem.